# Check calling convention of pointer-to-function type

Tags: c++, visual-c++, calling-convention

How to check at compile-time that function pointer has the `__stdcall` calling convention?

Something like

```
void foo() {}

static_assert(is_stdcall<decltype(&foo)>::value, "foo() must be stdcall");
```

or at least

```
must_be_stdcall<T>(); // compiler error or warning if not stdcall
```

Comment: If you're talking about compile-time, then presumably you want to check *functions*, not *function-pointers*?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth : function-pointers _types_.

Comment: @Abyx: If you define a *function-pointer* type, you know by definition what its calling convention is.  Why would you need to check it?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: if it's a template parameter, I don't know its type.

Comment: @Abyx: Yes, with templates, that makes sense.  Even so, why does it matter what the convention is?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: "why" - is another question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MSVC has the [C4440 compiler warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbsa2yce.aspx):

```
// library code

#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(error: 4440)
template<typename F> void must_be_stdcall(F*) { typedef F __stdcall* T; }
#pragma warning(pop)

// test code

void __stdcall stdcall_fn() {}
void __cdecl cdecl_fn() {}

int main()
{
    must_be_stdcall(&stdcall_fn); // OK
    must_be_stdcall(&cdecl_fn); // error
}
```

It may be `typedef decltype(foo) __stdcall* T;` where `foo` is a function (note, that there should be `foo`, not `&foo`), but it doesn't works with static member functions.